# NiFi: poor performance of ConsumeKafkaRecord_2_0 and ConsumeKafka_2_0

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I'm trying to load messages from relatively large topic (billion+ records, more then 100 GiB, single partition) using Apache NiFi (nifi-1.11.4-RC1, OpenJDK 8, RHEL7), but performance seems to be far too low:

1248429 messages (276.2 MB) per 5 minutes for **ConsumeKafka_2_0** and 295 batches (282.5 MB) for **ConsumeKafkaRecord_2_0**. I.e. **only 4161 messages (920 KB) per second**.

Results of **kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh** (same node, same consumer group and same topic) are more impressive:
**263.4 MB (1190937 records) per second**. Too much difference for any reasonable overhead.

I've configured cluster according to [Best practices for setting up a high performance NiFi installation](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/HDF-CFM-NIFI-Best-practices-for-setting-up-a-high/ta-p/244999), but throughput didn't increase.

Each node has 256 GB RAM and 20 cores, **Maximum Timer Driven Thread Count** is set to 120, but NiFi GUI shows only 1 or 2 active threads, and CPU load is almost zero, so is disk queue.

I've tested several flows, but even ConsumeKafka_2_0 with autoterminated 'success' relationship shows the same speed.

Is it possible to increase performance of these processors? It looks like some artificial limit or throttle, because I couldn't find any bottleneck...

Help, please, I'm completely stuck!

**UPD1:**

```
    # JVM memory settings
    java.arg.2=-Xms10240m
    java.arg.3=-Xmx10240m
```

**Scheduling Strategy** : Timer driven

**Concurrent Tasks** : 64

**Run Schedule** : 0 sec

**Execution** : All nodes

**Maximum Timer Driven Thread Count** : 120

**Maximum Event Driven Thread Count** : 20

**UPD2:**

When I consume topic with many partitions or several topics together with one ConsumeKafka_2_0 processor, or when I use several processors with different consumer groups with same topic, total throughput increases accordingly.

So, **Maximum Timer Driven Thread Count** and **Concurrent Tasks** aren't primary culprits. Problem is somewhere in task scheduling, or in processor itself.

Comment: Update post with the min/max memory for Nifi.  Update post with scheduling and concurrency for Consume Proc.   Take a look at min/max thread pool for NiFi to allow cranking up more concurrency and active threads.  Consider Garbage Collection tuning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've had success increasing ConsumeKafka throughput by changing the processor's yield duration from 1 to 0 seconds and increasing the socket's buffer size to 1 MB.

```
receive.buffer.bytes=1048576
```

You may find other things to try here:
https://blog.newrelic.com/engineering/kafka-best-practices/